# Not able to import deepgram-sdk

Tags: python, installation, libraries

I'm new to deepgram-sdk library and have tried running the following command to install it

`pip3 install deepgram-sdk`

I even checked the libraries installed by typing: `pip3 list`

And I was able to see that `deepgram-sdk 0.3.0` was installed but I am still not able to import it.

Please help

Error:

```
from deepgram import Deepgram
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deepgram'
```

Comment: Do you have multiple Python versions installed? Is your `pip3` associated with a different `python3`?